# moment: Array.prototype.some called on null or undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, momentjs, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

Still stuck in the following problem. I did not have the problem last week and I did not change any codes:
I am using daterangepicker here:http://www.daterangepicker.com/#usage

My js codes:

```
const Backbone = require('backbone');
const dutils = require('dutils');
const FilterGroupView = require('./filterGroupView');
const _ = require('underscore');
const $ = require('jquery');
const moment = require('bootstrap-daterangepicker/moment');
require('bootstrap-daterangepicker');

const ranges = {
  'Today': [moment().startOf('day'), moment()],
  'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days').startOf('day'), moment().subtract(1, 'days').endOf('day')],
  'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(7, 'days'), moment()],
  'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(30, 'days'), moment()],
  'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
  'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')],
};

$('#dateForm').val(moment().subtract(7, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm') + ' - ' + moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
console.log('ranges:' + JSON.stringify(ranges) ); // eslint-disable-line no-console
$('#dateForm').daterangepicker({
  format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
  minDate: new Date(2014, 0, 1),
  maxDate: new Date(),
  timePicker: true,
  timePickerIncrement: 30,
  showDropdowns: true,
  ranges: ranges, // Here
}, (start, end, label) => {
  $('#dateForm').val(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm') + ' - ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
  if (label !== 'Custom Range') {
    this._relative_date = label;
  } else {
    this._relative_date = false;
  }
});
```

log in console.log is below:

```
analytics.bundle.js?v=v1.71:2 ranges:{"Today":["2016-04-18T04:00:00.000Z","2016-04-18T17:51:28.384Z"],"Yesterday":["2016-04-17T04:00:00.000Z","2016-04-18T03:59:59.999Z"],"Last 7 Days":["2016-04-11T17:51:28.385Z","2016-04-18T17:51:28.385Z"],"Last 30 Days":["2016-03-19T17:51:28.385Z","2016-04-18T17:51:28.385Z"],"This Month":["2016-04-01T04:00:00.000Z","2016-05-01T03:59:59.999Z"],"Last Month":["2016-03-01T05:00:00.000Z","2016-04-01T03:59:59.999Z"]}
```

The above log shows that ranges is OK. The error in console.log is as following. If I removed "      ranges: ranges, // Here" in the above code, the error will disappear. I cannot figure out why.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Array.prototype.some called on null or undefined
```

Details of the error:

```
c   @   analytics.bundle.js?v=v1.71:16
Ue  @   analytics.bundle.js?v=v1.71:17
me  @   analytics.bundle.js?v=v1.71:17
n.setOptions    @   analytics.bundle.js?v=v1.71:16
n   @   analytics.bundle.js?v=v1.71:16
(anonymous function)    @   analytics.bundle.js?v=v1.71:16
vt.extend.each  @   commons.bundle.js?v=v1.71:14
vt.fn.vt.each   @   commons.bundle.js?v=v1.71:14
$.fn.daterangepicker    @   analytics.bundle.js?v=v1.71:16
t.exports.i.View.extend.initialize  @   analytics.bundle.js?v=v1.71:2
e.View  @   commons.bundle.js?v=v1.71:31
n   @   commons.bundle.js?v=v1.71:32
t.exports.i.View.extend.initialize  @   analytics.bundle.js?v=v1.71:1
e.View  @   commons.bundle.js?v=v1.71:31
n   @   commons.bundle.js?v=v1.71:32
(anonymous function)    @   analytics.bundle.js?v=v1.71:1
h   @   commons.bundle.js?v=v1.71:24
c.fireWith  @   commons.bundle.js?v=v1.71:24
vt.extend.ready @   commons.bundle.js?v=v1.71:24
c   @   commons.bundle.js?v=v1.71:14
```

part of package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "backbone": "^1.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.4",
    "bootstrap-daterangepicker": "git://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker.git#v1.3.21",
    "bootstrap-notify": "^3.1.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.12.1",
    "datatables": "git://github.com/DataTables/DataTables.git#1.10.7",
    "expose-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^0.8.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.3.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "jquery": "^1.11.0",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.10.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.12.2",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.5"
  }
```

Comment: Hi, I'm from the Moment team. See below for what we believe is going on. We'll keep updating this issue for future finders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue appears to be coming from moment 2.13.0 which got released 11 hours ago from now. I assume your date picker is using moment as a dependency.

In the meantime...this should temporarily resolve your issue by downgrading the version.
`npm uninstall moment`
`npm i moment@2.12.0`

Update: I created an issue to track this.
https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3124

Comment: Yes, I used "const moment = require('bootstrap-daterangepicker/moment');" to import moment. In fact, I do not know which version of moment is imported. I am new to this project.

Comment: I am using moment 2.13.0

Comment: I updated my comment above with some further information

Comment: I just noticed that the bootstrap-daterangepicker updated 11 hours ago, but did not notice that moment released too. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help. Working with moment to fix it now on the github thread

Comment: Can confirm, downgrade the moment version fix the issue

Answer (score 2):

From the Moment team: We believe the issue you are seeing here is that due to packaging, Moment objects from pre 2.13 versions are being passed into moment functions in 2.13. Because of a change to internal variables in 2.13, things are not working correctly.

For now, downgrading moment to 2.12 will solve the issue.

We are going to talk to some of the authors of the more popular libraries that depend on this and see what we can do. We will track progress in https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3124 as mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: Thanks all of you.

Answer (score 0):

Updating moment.js to it's latest version of 2.24.0 solved this issue for me. It also fixed another issue where we were shown records with blank delivery dates. Those blank records stopped appearing after updating to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

For others that come across this issue, I encountered this problem when attempting to make a HTTP request whose POST body was an object with a value that was an instance of Moment:

```
body = {
  foo: moment()
}
```

It failed to serialize the moment() instance correctly, and I resolved by converting to an ISO8601 string:

```
body = {
  foo: moment().toISOString()
}
```